# Packager terminal is not shown in Linux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native and I use two machines while working on a demo project, an MS Windows (Win 10, at library) machine and a Linux machine (Linux Mint 19, at home.)

While working with the Windows machine, and after I start my application with `react-native run-android` a new terminal opens where node/packager runs.
In the Linux machine no other terminal opens, and in the original terminal (the one I used to start the app on the avd) I sometimes get the command line back (returns, so I can use it to enter any other command) and sometimes it just stops at this line: `Starting: Intent { cmp=com.myApp/.MainActivity }`

So my questions are:

- Which machine's behavior is the normal one?
- How can I get the, packager/node, terminal in Linux? (if possible)
- Should the command line return, or keep busy with the above mentioned line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux, metro server is started in background when you run `react-native run-android`, providing no logs. You can start it separately by running `npm start` in the root folder.

**UPDATE**
Te behavior of having the command line back and sometimes not is due to the packager: if it is running on background, you will not be able to use the command line

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have noticed also that node keeps running in the background after turning off the AVD. This behavior might be the reason why when I move to another project folder I keep getting the previous project.
I used `ps -A | grep node` to get the PID, and kill it manually with `kill -9 PID`.
I also noticed that if I get the terminal command line back, it means node server is still running from the previous run, which means I have to kill it manually.
Why doesn't node server exit normally after I close/turn off the AVD? Is this normal?

Comment: Because the nodejs packager is not aware of the AVD. The packager is a server that provides the js bundle to anyone who ask for it. You could run a single packager instance and get the bundle with multiple devices. If you change project, you have manually close the packager instance relative to the old project and start another one for the new project

Comment: Is there a way I can get a terminal for the node packager, just like in Windows? If yes, how?

Comment: @FaizLotfy yes, as I said in the answer, go in your project base directory and just run `npm start`. You will have a packager instance running in that terminal, then open another terminal and run `react-native run-android`